# Unable to call a function from my smart contract in react

Tags: solidity, blockchain, hardhat, react, dapp-debugging

So I have checked and the smart contract is working perfectly in hardhat but when I am call it in react I am facing problem

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.9.0;

contract chai {
    struct Memo {
        string name;
        string message;
        uint256 timestamp;
        address from;
    }

    Memo[] memos;
    address payable owner;

    constructor() {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    function buyChai(string memory name, string memory message) public payable {
        require(msg.value > 0, "Please pay greater than 0 ether");
        owner.transfer(msg.value);
        memos.push(Memo(name, message, block.timestamp, msg.sender));
    }

    function getMemos() public view returns (Memo[] memory) {
        return memos;
    }
}
```

This is the smartcontract

```
import { useState,useEffect, memo } from "react";
const Memos=({state})=>{
    const[memos,setMemos]=useState([]);
    const{contract}=state;

    useEffect(()=>{
        const memosMessage=async()=>{
            const memos=await contract.getMemos();
            setMemos(memos);
        };
        contract && memosMessage();
    },[contract]);

    return ( 
    <> 
        <p>Records</p>
        {memos.map((memo)=>{return(
        <table key={memo.timestamp}>
            <tbody>
                <tr>{memo.name}</tr>
                <tr>{memo.message}</tr>
                <tr>{String(memo.timestamp)}</tr>
                <tr>{memo.from}</tr>
         </tbody>
     </table>
      );
      })}
    </>
 );
};
export default Memos;
```

This is a Memos.js which is imported in App.js but I am finding this problem
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the ABI in code,

```
 const contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI,contract);
```

and pass this instance to get your contract data where ever required

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking the following:

1. Whether your .env is correct or not.
2. Whether contractAddres in App.jsx is provided as per your test network.